# Calculate median of aggregated rows?? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like the below

```
Name          Date          Hour     Score 
Bob       01 jan 2018        9       0
Bob       01 jan 2018        10      0
Bob       01 jan 2018        11      3.03
Bob       01 jan 2018        11      3.43
Bob       01 jan 2018        12      0
Bob       01 jan 2018        13      0
```

Now there's a package that runs and aggregates everything in this table, so that each Name has 1 row and 1 date per hour, with all other values aggregated up. Once this runs, the table looks like the below

```
Name          Date          Hour     Score 
Bob       01 jan 2018        9       0
Bob       01 jan 2018        10      0
Bob       01 jan 2018        11      3.23
Bob       01 jan 2018        12      0
Bob       01 jan 2018        13      0
```

As you can see, the score has been averaged across both the duplicate columns. The duplicate exsists because the user received more than 1 score in the same hour on the same day.

I have been asked for this to be the median instead of the average - is this even doable? From my understanding, in order for us to get the median we need to be able to count all of the different scores and then select the middle one - how can we do this if everything will be aggregated onto 1 row? The median of the above example should actually be 0.

Is this easily doable with SQL?
Thanks

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median

Comment: Thanks, I read this but it didn't help me with my issue of everything being aggregated to 1 one per user,day and hour?

Comment: You need to modify the first query to calculate the median, you cannot decompose a single aggregated average value into anything else.  (Ofc if there are always only 2 values then median is the same as average).

Comment: If you have two values, the median *is* the average.  If you have three, they are probably pretty close.  I don't see that a median fits your needs.  Why would you want the median value from *other hours*?  That doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do median on the initial dataset with PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql

However if the data is already aggregated to average and you have lost the initial dataset, in that case you can't have median calculation anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This was fun, check this out :)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#media') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #media
CREATE TABLE #media(name nvarchar(100), [date] date not null, [hour] int, score numeric(12,2) not null)

INSERT INTO #media 
VALUES
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',9,0),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',10,0),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',11,3.03),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',11,3.43),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',12,0),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',13,0),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',23,11),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',23,12),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',23,13),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',23,14),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',23,15),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',23,19),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',22,21),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',22,22),
    ('Bob','2018-04-12',22,22)

SELECT * FROM #media ORDER BY name,[date],[hour]

SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    name,[date],[hour],
    (PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score)   OVER (PARTITION BY name,[date],[hour])) as score_media
FROM #media

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#media') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #media
```

Data before

```
name    date    hour    score
Bob 2018-04-12  9   0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  10  0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  11  3.03
Bob 2018-04-12  11  3.43
Bob 2018-04-12  12  0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  13  0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  22  21.00
Bob 2018-04-12  22  22.00
Bob 2018-04-12  22  22.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  11.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  12.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  13.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  14.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  15.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  19.00
```

Data after

```
name    date    hour    score_media
Bob 2018-04-12  9   0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  10  0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  11  3.03
Bob 2018-04-12  12  0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  13  0.00
Bob 2018-04-12  22  22.00
Bob 2018-04-12  23  13.00
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is what you want

```
select name, date, hour, avg(score)
from table
group by name, date, hour;
```